# Invalid table alias when joining multiple tables in hive

Tags: join, hive

Can someone identify why this multi-table join is not accepted?  When I bring in the third table, it then fails with invalid table alias.  I am not seeing what is wrong:

This works (two table):

```
select  
 a.ri as `R_ID`
,oc3.name as `RET`
,a.rch as `RC`
from dev.sl a join dev.codes oc3 
    on (a.pk_business = oc3.pk_business 
    and a.pk_data_source = oc3.pk_data_source 
    and a.pk_frequency = oc3.pk_frequency 
    and oc3.pk_data_state = '123'
    and oc3.code = a.ri and oc3.codeset = 'xyz')
```

Then add a third table and it fails:
(Three table):

```
select  
 a.ri as `R_ID`
,oc3.name as `RET`
,a.rch as `RC`
from dev.sl a join dev.codes oc3 
    on (a.pk_business = oc3.pk_business 
    and a.pk_data_source = oc3.pk_data_source 
    and a.pk_frequency = oc3.pk_frequency 
    and oc3.pk_data_state = '123'
    and oc3.code = a.ri and oc3.codeset = 'xyz') join dev.items b 
on (b.pk_business = a.pk_business 
and b.pk_data_source = a.pk_data_source 
and b.pk_frequency = a.pk_frequency 
and b.pk_data_state = '123' 
and a.ii = b.item_id 
and a.cc = b.country_code)
```

SemanticException [Error 10009]: Line 1:2920 Invalid table alias 'a':

Comment: show us your create table statements

Answer (score 0):

I have an update - it seems that this was caused by having one table created as an updatable table (TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true')), and one without, and with my session settings of:

```
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

This caused the problem.  On another session without the settings AND repointing to an identical table "a" created as a non-ACID type table, the multi-table join worked fine.  I don't know enough about HIVE to know why - I suspect that a transactional and non-transactional table cannot be joined in the same "transaction" (select statement).

Answer (score 0):

One more update - It may not be due to the transactional table.  With additional testing, I now also see it happens with non-transactional tables as well.  It seems that the three table join works when I execute it from a putty session directly on the server, but when I use SQL Developer, it will produce the aforementioned error.  It appears to be an issue with SQL Developer, but why still is unknown.

Comment: What do you mean by sql Developer